# Wordpress is killing my script

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get a simple jquery script running on my wordpress site. The script should show a new tab with different text when I press a link but when instead it just refreshes the page and shows the same information.

The script works fine when I'm not running wordpress, but I have to use wordpress.

My code

```
        <form class="form">
            <div class="tabs">
                <div class="tab-1 tab">
                    <h2>Hvor mange undersider har du brug for? </h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pede et mattis, velit est wisi convallis sit, wisi leo pulvinar, elit non et nunc, est penatibus at. Eget duis pretium vel, posuere ac et, augue eget eu a a, ac sapien, egestas luctus eros</p>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                        1-5
                        </label>
                        <input name="sider" type="radio" value="1" >
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>
                        6-10
                        </label>
                        <input name="sider" type="radio" value="2" >
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>
                        11-15
                        </label>
                        <input name="sider" type="radio" value="3" >
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>
                        16-20
                        </label>
                        <input name="sider" type="radio" value="4" >
                    </div>

                    <a data-tab="2" class="tab-change btn btn-success pull-right" href="#" >Gå til næste fane</a>


                </div>

                <div class="tab-2 tab">
                    <h2>Skal din hjemmeside udvikles fra bunden eller ud fra et tema?</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pede et mattis, velit est wisi convallis sit, wisi leo pulvinar, elit non et nunc, est penatibus at. Eget duis pretium vel, posuere ac et, augue eget eu a a, ac sapien, egestas luctus eros</p>

                    <div>
                        <label>
                        Fra bunden
                        </label>
                        <input name="tema" type="radio" value="10" >



                        <label>
                        Fra et tema
                        </label>
                        <input name="tema" type="radio" value="2" >
                   </div>


                    <a data-tab="3" class="tab-change btn btn-success pull-right" href="#" >Gå til næste fane</a>
                    <a data-tab="1" class="tab-change btn btn-danger pull-left" href="#" >Gå tilbage</a>

                </div>

                <div class="tab-3 tab">
                    <h2>Har din side brug for specielle funktioner?</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pede et mattis, velit est wisi convallis sit, wisi leo pulvinar, elit non et nunc, est penatibus at. Eget duis pretium vel, posuere ac et, augue eget eu a a, ac sapien, egestas luctus eros</p>
                    <a data-tab="4" class="tab-change btn btn-success pull-right" href="#" >Gå til næste fane</a>
                    <a data-tab="2" class="tab-change btn btn-danger pull-left" href="#" >Gå tilbage</a>

                </div>

                <div class="tab-4 tab">
                    <h2>Har du brug for en ny farveidentitet?</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pede et mattis, velit est wisi convallis sit, wisi leo pulvinar, elit non et nunc, est penatibus at. Eget duis pretium vel, posuere ac et, augue eget eu a a, ac sapien, egestas luctus eros</p>
                    <a data-tab="5" class="tab-change btn btn-success pull-right" href="#" >Gå til næste fane</a>
                    <a data-tab="3" class="tab-change btn btn-danger pull-left" href="#" >Gå tilbage</a>

                </div>

                <div class="tab-5 tab">
                    <h2>Har du brug for oplæring i hjemmesiden?</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pede et mattis, velit est wisi convallis sit, wisi leo pulvinar, elit non et nunc, est penatibus at. Eget duis pretium vel, posuere ac et, augue eget eu a a, ac sapien, egestas luctus eros</p>
                    <a data-tab="6" class="tab-change btn btn-success pull-right" href="#" >Gå til næste fane</a>
                    <a data-tab="4" class="tab-change btn btn-danger pull-left" href="#" type="submit">Gå tilbage</a>

                </div>

                <div class="tab-6 tab">
                    <h2>Prisen på din nye hjemmeside er næsten klar</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pede et mattis, velit est wisi convallis sit, wisi leo pulvinar, elit non et nunc, est penatibus at. Eget duis pretium vel, posuere ac et, augue eget eu a a, ac sapien, egestas luctus eros</p>


                    <form action="/action_page.php">
                        Navn:<br>
                        <input type="text" name="Navn" value="Navn">
                        <br>
                        Virksomhed:<br>
                        <input type="text" name="Virksomhed" value="virksomhed">
                        <br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                    <a data-tab="4" class="tab-change btn btn-danger pull-left" href="#" type="submit">Gå tilbage</a>

                </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <h3>
        Din pris
      </h3>
        <p class="pris">

        </p>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>

   (function($){
$.unserialize = function(serializedString){
    var str = decodeURI(serializedString);
    var pairs = str.split('&');
    var obj = {}, p, idx, val;
    for (var i=0, n=pairs.length; i < n; i++) {
        p = pairs[i].split('=');
        idx = p[0];

        if (idx.indexOf("[]") == (idx.length - 2)) {
            // Eh um vetor
            var ind = idx.substring(0, idx.length-2)
            if (obj[ind] === undefined) {
                obj[ind] = [];
            }
            obj[ind].push(p[1]);
        }
        else {
            obj[idx] = p[1];
        }
    }
    return obj;
};})(jQuery);

    function calculateTotalTabs(tab){
        var totalTabs = $('.tab').length;
        var procent = tab/totalTabs*100;

        $('.progress-bar').css({
            width: procent+'%'
        }).text(tab+'/'+totalTabs);
    }

    calculateTotalTabs(1);


  $('.tab-change').click(function(){
     var tab = $(this).data('tab');
     $('.tab:visible').hide();
     $('.tab-'+tab).show();

     calculateTotalTabs(tab);
     calculatePrice();
  });

$('.form input').change(function(){
    calculatePrice();
})

function calculatePrice(){
    var timepris = 650;
    var data = $.unserialize($('.form').serialize());
    var total = 0;
    $.each(data,function(index,value){
        if(!isNaN(parseInt(value))){
            total += parseInt(value);
        }
    })
    var totalPris = total*timepris;
    $('.pris').text(totalPris+'kr')
}


  </script>
```

Any clue what I could do to get this working?

Comment: Check for JavaScript errors in your console. A failed JavaScript function might not capture the click properly and then the page reloads. You can set your JavaScript debugger, in browser, to stop on any line that produces an error, too.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your wordpress site is running jQuery in noConflict mode...

```js
$.noConflict();

(function($){
  $(document.body).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
  
  doSomethingElse();
}(jQuery));

function doSomethingElse () {
  $(document.body).css('backgroundColor', 'green');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will error because the `doSomethingElse` method is referencing `$` as jQuery outside of the IIFE which passes jQuery in as `$`.  Meanwhile the following will work.

```js
$.noConflict();

(function($){
  $(document.body).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
  
  doSomethingElse();
}(jQuery));

function doSomethingElse () {
  jQuery(document.body).css('backgroundColor', 'green');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This works because the method outside the IIFE uses `jQuery` and not `$`.  The following will also work...

```js
$.noConflict();

(function($){
  $(document.body).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
  
  doSomethingElse();

  function doSomethingElse () {
    $(document.body).css('backgroundColor', 'green');
  }
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This works because the function is declared inside the IIFE where `$` is understood to be jQuery.